# Refreshing WPF DataView after replacing ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpf-controls, observablecollection

I have 3 methods that returns a List collection and I cannot change them.

```
    List<Person> GetListPerson()
    {
        List <Person> list = new List<Person>();
        list.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Judge", LastName = "Mental" });
        list.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Office", LastName = "Rocker" });
        list.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Sir", LastName = "Real" });

        return list;
    }

    List<Person> GetOnePerson()
    {
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
        list.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Josh", LastName = "Smith" });
        return list;
    }

    List<Person> ClearPerson()
    {
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
        return list;
    }
```

In my XAML I have a 3 buttons and a grid with binding to a observable collection

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <Button Name="GetList" Height="30" Content="GetList" Click="GetList_Click"  />
    <Button Name="GetOne" Height="30"  Content="GetOne" Click="GetOne_Click"/>
    <Button Name="Clear" Height="30" Content="Clear" Click="Clear_Click" />
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Height="230" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
</StackPanel>
```

This is the code behind:

```
private ObservableCollection<Person> _pObsList;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> PObsList
    {
        get { return _pObsList; }
        set { _pObsList = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("PObsList");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(
                this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PObsList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        dataGrid.DataContext = PObsList;
    }


    private void GetList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PObsList = new ObservableCollection<Person>(GetListPerson());
    }

    private void GetOne_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PObsList = new ObservableCollection<Person>(GetOnePerson());
    }

    private void Clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PObsList = new ObservableCollection<Person>(ClearPerson());
    }
```

When the app is run, the grid will display the columns but no records as expected; but if clicking GetList button, my Observable collection will contain 3 elements, but the DataGrid will remain empty.

By reading other links, it seems that I need to implement PropertyChanged on the Collection, but I think something else is missing.

It is not possible to change the Lists to Observable collection and I am trying not to clear and add them manually.

Any idea or help?

Comment: And  where  do you set you binding to your observableCollection ?   <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Height="230" ItemsSource="{Binding}" /> Binding what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is the `DataContext`. When you change the `PObsList` in any of the 3 event handlers, you just set a new value for `PObsList`, the `DataContext` will remain the original `PObsList`. I suggest to use a separate object (a viewmodel) with an `ObservableCollection` property to use as `DataContext`, not an `ObservableCollection` directly.

Comment: The problem is that when he opening the window, there is no data in that grid. And this is because PObsList is empty ...  look at the constructor. He initialize PObsList  but he never add values . Only when he press the buttons

Comment: Agree, modifying the ObservableCollection is the cleanest way, but he explicitly doesn't want to do that. The next best thing is to have an indirection so that at least the notification for the full collection swap is processed correctly.

Comment: "When the app is run, the grid will display the columns but no records as expected;  ".....

Comment: Thanks Szabolcs!! You were right, I needed to specify the DataContext by using another class with a ObservableCollection property. My mistake is trying to do everything in the window.

Comment: ViewModel must implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

In the click handlers you override the `PObsList` variable. 
Clear the list and add the new items from the methods:

```
PObsList.Clear();
PObsList.AddRange(GetListPerson());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put a breakpoint in your

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    PObsList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    dataGrid.DataContext = PObsList;
}
```

you`ll see that PObsList  is empty.

When you press GetList button, your list is not empty because  your method GetListPerson return a list with values.

You can change to :

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PObsList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        PObsList.AddRange(GetPersonList());
        dataGrid.DataContext = PObsList;
    }
```